# Ignoring WHERE condition QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

How can I create SQL like this in QueryDSL.

```
SELECT NAME FROM TB_NAMES
WHERE 1 = 1
AND NAME = 'JOHN'
```

ignoring the `WHERE` condition and add only `AND's`

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand the meaning of `where` clause. The `AND's` are a part of it.

Comment: why not SELECT NAME FROM TB_NAMES WHERE NAME = 'JOHN' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all names that are equals John:

```
new JPAQuery<T>(EntityManager, HQLTemplates.DEFAULT).from(qEntity.name).where(qEntity.name.eq("John")).fetch();
```